# How to I correctly change the default data directory for Docker?

Tags: systemd, docker

We have `docker-ce` running on some Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machines. The machines have a fast SSD for the OS, and a ZFS array for heavy data like docker containers.

Every time I'm brought in to fix the docker setup, it appears that an update reset the configuration to use the ZFS array for it's data.

That's probably because most guides are quite old. My changes, [inspired by this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux), are like so:

In `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`, add `-g "/mnt/var/lib/docker"` like so:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g "/mnt/var/lib/docker" -H fd://
```

Also postpone the start of the service until the ZFS array is online:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target docker.socket firewalld.service zfs-mount.service
```

Even though this appears to be the recommended way to add a different directory according to the docs and old articles, this must be outdated because this file is reset on *every* update, and I have to manually change them back. After restarting the service, it works fine until the next update.

#### What is the proper way to make these changes stick while the package is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has do with `systemd` uses files.

As documented in `man file-hierarchy`, the `/lib` directory is for read-only vendor-supplied files, while `/etc` is for "system-specific configuration", which may override the default vendor-supplied files in `/lib`.

The correct place to place your modifications are in `/etc/sytemd/system`.

You can either completely replace the file in question with a file in `/etc/` or you use a "drop-in" template to override only part of the file.

Search `man systemd.unit` for "Drop-in" for the details.

Files in `/lib` will continue to get overwritten during package upgrades, while changes to `/etc/` will be preserved.

The advice about /lib vs /etc applies generally, not just to `systemd`.

### systemd drop-in unit example

In `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-fix-execstart.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g "/mnt/var/lib/docker" -H fd://
```

So, you are following a pattern to create a file in a directory named after the service you want to override, declaring just the specific section and directive you want to override.

From `man systemd.service`:

> *If the empty string is assigned to this option, the list of commands to start is reset, prior assignments of this option will have no effect.*

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted your answer. However, if you'd create an example for the drop-in or quote the documentation in your answer, as per stack exchange recommendations, that would be great for the next person that comes along from google.

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: Had to do this on a different machine. Extra info: After adding the `drop-in` files, before updating, run `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: I don't know how I did this before. I'm getting `docker.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.` __-update-__ Solution [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14491#issuecomment-119873335).

Comment: @Redsandro, I updated my answer to reflect what's needed, which comes from the documentation for the `ExecStart=` directive in `man systemd.service`. Any time you having a problem with a systemd directive, use `man systemd.directives` to check the primary documentation for the directive first.

Comment: Thank you @MarkStosberg. I can't upvote more, but I appreciate it. I hope people that come from google will give you some upvotes. If people upvote my question too, it will get ranked higher.